# Close Button in Alert not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following:

Markup:

```js
angular.module('web').controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [];
  $scope.alerts.push({
    type: 'danger',
    msg: 'I am an error'
  });
  $scope.alerts.push({
    type: 'danger',
    msg: 'I am an error'
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<html>

<body ng-app="web">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
};

function addError(error) {
    $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'danger', msg: error.data });
}
```

But the Close button is not showed:

[image]

Can Anyone help me show the close button?

I'm creating the scafolding of the project with Grunt and bower.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that when you have multiple times defined the 'alert' array and the close attribute the 'X' dissapear.

I presume that this could happen because the boolean that define if it should be showed is changed after seeing multiple times the variable, is toggled.

Thanks for your help :)

I hope this help anyone.

Answer (score 2):

While maybe not the solution to *your* problem, I found, that using `ng-bind` along with a dismissable alert removes the close button, too (since `ng-bind` controls the entire content of the element).

So you should always use the `{{ alert.message }}` notation to display the alert content.

Comment: If you can't use ng-bind, but you want to have messages that are HTML, is there another way to do this? My solution was 

     <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="alert.close()">
          <span ng-bind-html="alert.msg"></span></alert>

Comment: @Corey Looks fine, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid using `{{alert.msg}}` (that can be ugly sometimes) you can use:

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">
   <div ng-bind="alert.msg"></div>
</alert>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to use `ng-click` in the 'X' with a closeAlert function.
I add a ng-repeat to the alert arrays based on `ui-bootstrap`.
You can check it out here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hcVlFZ2yZzLHaUahXaJK

Hope it helps.